# Inbox, Achievements sections are not responding when no entry in the "reputation" tab in Area 51

Tags: bug, area-51, top-bar, global-inbox, achievements-dialog

When selecting the "reputation" tab, if there is no entry in it and clicking on the Inbox and Achievements section, they are not responding in the [Area 51 page](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/146705/arulkumar?tab=reputation).

GIF for the same:

[image: Area 51 - Inbox, Achievements are not responding]

**Update:**

When reputation is displaying in the top bar, if there is no entry in the "reputation" tab, the reputation indicator in the top bar is hiding.

[image: Reputation display issue]